# Why Latent Space in Stable Diffusion has shape 64x64x3?

Tags: deep-learning, vae, diffusion

I am wondering why the dimensionality of `Latent Space` in `Stable Diffusion` is `64x64x3`. Since the encoding is performed by `Variational Autoencoder` it must output some `mean` and `log variance` that we can use to sample a `latent vector` of shape `(latent_dim, )`. But how `Stable Diffusion` uses `64x64x3` latent space when we expect shape `(latent, )`?